# how to stack two div containers both taking up the screen size responsively

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I have a website (www.phillipemersonjones.com).  I'm trying to make the first image take up the entire screen responsively.  then when you scroll down the second image does the same thing as well.  I've searched but haven't found a solution that works.

current css:

```
.contact_body {
  background-color: #495A6B;

}

.jumbotron-1 {
    position: relative;
    background: #000 image-url('mountain.jpg')center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 850px;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.jumbotron-3 {
    position: relative;
    background: #000 image-url('bluewall.jpg') center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 850px;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.jumbo-h1 {
  padding-top: 50px
}
.about-pic {
  padding-top: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.about-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}
.navbar {
   background-color: transparent;
   background: transparent;
   border-color: transparent;
}
.navbar li { color: #000 }
.jumbotron-2 {
    margin-top: -29px;
    position: relative;
    background: #000 image-url('apartments.jpg') center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 850px;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.portfolio {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.portfolio-img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
.portfolio-img1 {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #000 url("http://gdriv.es/pjimg/01.jpg");
    color: black;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-family: monospace;
}
.portfolio-img2 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background: #000 url("http://gdriv.es/pjimg/02.jpg");
  color: black;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.contact_form {
    padding-top: 90px;
}
.email_error {
  opacity: 0.6;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: black;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

html

```
<% content_for :title do %>Phillip Jones Personal Portfolio Webpage<% end %>
<% content_for :body_class, "contact_body" %>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Phillip Emerson Jones</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role='menu'>
            <li ><a href="https://creamrises.herokuapp.com" >AngularJS App</a></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Reservation app", new_reservation_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Movies app", movies_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Todos app", todos_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Blog app", messages_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><%= link_to 'About', about_path %></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!-- end container -->
<div id="about" class="jumbotron-1">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <h1 class="jumbo-h1">Phillip Emerson Jones</h1>
        <p>Web/Software Development Professional</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#contact"><i class="about-arrow fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-4x text-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="contact" class="jumbotron-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h1 class="jumbo-h1">Contact</h1>
        <p>phillip@phillipemersonjones.com</p>
        <p>shoot me a line</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/phillipjones2" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100006745729075" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="https://github.com/phillipjones2" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-github fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <a href="#about"><i class="about-arrow fa fa-arrow-circle-up fa-4x text-center" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: which all browser you want to support? If you are not thinking of older browser try using "vh".

Comment: http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/QwErXZ check this demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick to get a div to take up 100% of the screenheight is to set the height of the html and body tags (and any parent divs as well!).

```css
html,body { 
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.full-height {
  height: 100%
}

#about {
  background: #0000ff;
}

#contact {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="about" class="full-height"></div>
<div id="contact" class="full-height"></div>
```

Here is a fiddle of another example with a parent div: https://jsfiddle.net/n835ngnw/

Comment: www.phillipemersonjones.com  I have a scroll bar at the bottom now.  Suggestions on how to remove this would be appreciated!!

Comment: Remove this after your body tag:

`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: That didn't remove the scroll bar.  any other suggestions?

Comment: If you remove it with the page inspector it works. But without seeing you actual code it's difficult to tell the real reason. Good luck figuring it out! ;)